# Add carousel functionality to tabs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, carousel

I am looking for some way to implement a carousel with my tabs, or to write other code for tabs with carousel functionality.

I have written code to make "prev" and "next" buttons.

Now I want to show only 5 tabs on the screen.

Suppose I have 8 tabs and I'm looking at tabs 1 through 5, so tabs 6, 7, 8 are hidden.

When I'm on tab number 5 and click on the "next" button, I want to show tab 6 and hide tab 1. That's how a carousel is supposed to work. I'm not sure how to change my code to do this.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.next-tab').click(function() {
    // get current tab
    var currentTab = $(".tab.active");

    // get the next tab, if there is one
    var newTab = currentTab.next();

    // at the end, so go to the first one
    if (newTab.length === 0) {
      newTab = $(".tab").first();
    }

    currentTab.removeClass('active');
    // add active to new tab
    newTab.addClass('active');
  });

  $('.prev-tab').click(function() {
    // get current tab
    var currentTab = $(".tab.active");

    // get the previous tab, if there is one
    var newTab = currentTab.prev();

    // at the start, so go to the last one
    if (newTab.length === 0) {
      newTab = $(".tab").last();
    }

    currentTab.removeClass('active');
    // add active to new tab
    newTab.addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="next-tab">next</a>
<a href="#" class="prev-tab">prev</a>

<div class="tabs">

  <a href="#" class="tab new-messages">Messages</a>
  <a href="#" class="tab statistics active">Stats</a>
  <a href="#" class="tab shop">Shop</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `active` class to look up the currently active tab, you can use an index into an array of tabs. Indexing lets you calculate the carousel's movement with modulo arithmetic.

Suppose the active tab is at `currentIndex` and the total number of tabs is `numTotal`. This calculation shifts the index to the left:

```
currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + numTotal) % numTotal;
```

And to the right:

```
currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % numTotal;
```

To show a limited number of tabs at a time, keep track of the indices of the leftmost visible and rightmost visible tabs.

Suppose the index of the leftmost visible tab is called `left`. Then you can check if the new value of `currentIndex` has gone to the left of `left`:

```
if (currentIndex === (left - 1 + numTotal) % numTotal)
```

If it has, you should update `left`:

```
left = (left - 1 + numTotal) % numTotal;
```

You also want to make sure that the new leftmost tab appears to the left of the old current tab:

```
$(tabs[left]).insertBefore(currentTab);
```

This is important when you're wrapping around the end of the array. For example, if your tabs are numbered 0 through 9 and you shift from tab 0 toward the left, you want tab 9 to be inserted to the left of tab 0.

Then you make the new leftmost tab visible, hide the old rightmost tab and update the right index:

```
$(tabs[left]).css('display', 'inline');
$(tabs[right]).css('display', 'none');
right = (right - 1 + numTotal) % numTotal;
```

You have to carry out similar operations when you shift the active tab to the right. It's tricky to do everything in the correct order, so I've made the following snippet to demonstrate how it's done.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tabs = $('.tab'),                       // Make an array of tabs.
      numTotal = tabs.length,
      numVisible = Math.min(numTotal, 5),
      currentIndex = 0,
      currentTab = tabs[currentIndex],
      left = currentIndex,                    // Track the leftmost and
      right = currentIndex + numVisible - 1;  // rightmost visible tabs.
  
  $(tabs).each(function (index, tab) {        // Let each tab update
    $(tab).click(function () {                // currentIndex to point
      $(currentTab).removeClass('active');    // to itself when clicked.
      currentTab = tabs[currentIndex = index];
      $(currentTab).addClass('active');
    });
  });
  $(tabs).css('display', 'none');             // Hide all tabs.
  for (var i = left; i <= right; ++i) {
    $(tabs[i]).css('display', 'inline');      // Show visible tabs.
  }
  $(currentTab).addClass('active');
  
  $('#prevButton').click(function () {
    $(currentTab).removeClass('active');
    currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + numTotal) % numTotal;
    if (currentIndex === (left - 1 + numTotal) % numTotal) {
      // Shift visible span to the left.
      left = (left - 1 + numTotal) % numTotal;
      $(tabs[left]).insertBefore(currentTab); // Ensure we wrap around.
      $(tabs[left]).css('display', 'inline');
      $(tabs[right]).css('display', 'none');
      right = (right - 1 + numTotal) % numTotal;
    }
    currentTab = tabs[currentIndex];
    $(currentTab).addClass('active');
  });

  $('#nextButton').click(function() {
    $(currentTab).removeClass('active');
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % numTotal;
    if (currentIndex === (right + 1) % numTotal) {
      // Shift visible span to the right.
      $(tabs[left]).css('display', 'none');
      left = (left + 1) % numTotal;
      right = (right + 1) % numTotal;
      $(tabs[right]).css('display', 'inline');
      $(tabs[right]).insertAfter(currentTab); // Ensure we wrap around.
    }
    currentTab = tabs[currentIndex];
    $(currentTab).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#buttons, #tabs {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#buttons a {
  color: #444;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
#tabs a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #0090ad;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
#tabs a.active {
  background: #2c4fad;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="buttons">
  <a href="#" id="prevButton">prev</a>
  <a href="#" id="nextButton">next</a>
</div>

<div id="tabs">
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab0"> Tab 0 </a>
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab1"> Tab 1 </a>
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab2"> Tab 2 </a>
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab3"> Tab 3 </a>
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab4"> Tab 4 </a>
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab5"> Tab 5 </a>
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab6"> Tab 6 </a>
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab7"> Tab 7 </a>
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab8"> Tab 8 </a>
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab9"> Tab 9 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Michael Laszlo, one more question, right now tabs not working with "onclick". how can we add this functionality? so i can click on some tab and the tab become active and the index will updated.

Comment: Please see the revised code. It now adds a click handler to each tab.